# WSL displays lots of empty lines when running PowerShell commands

Tags: linux, windows, bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In WSL, I sometimes want to run PowerShell commands, but it weirdly creates a ton of empty lines. How do I prevent these empty lines from spamming my console or script output?

```
# Example1 (from Ubuntu or CentOS WSL console):
$ hostname -I | clip.exe   # Use DOS command to collect IP into clipboard
$ powershell.exe /c "get-clipboard"   # Correctly displays the IP, but then also 15 empty lines(!)

# Example2 (from Ubuntu or CentOS WSL console):
# To alter the jarring Windows Event sounds that affect WSL sessions by updating the default sounds
$ powershell.exe '$toChange = @(".Default","SystemAsterisk","SystemExclamation","Notification.Default","SystemNotification","WindowsUAC","SystemHand"); foreach ($c in $toChange) { Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\$c\.Current\" -Name "(Default)" -Value "C:\WINDOWS\media\ding.wav" }'
```

In both cases, the console is spammed by 15 lines of dead space ...

I thought I would try and redirect to `>/dev/null`, but that's even worse, the WSL console changes font and resizes the screen in a very strange way.

Help on this would be good, as within the WSL context, I will have to make calls with PowerShell commands for some things that I'm doing (to update registry etc).

Comment: could you just assign the output a variable and use the .Trim() method? I'm guessing you want a long term fix and not something that you have to do all the time...

Comment: For sure, a workable long-term solution is needed I think, as it's quite odd to me that this happens (and does not happen with DOS commands). I just tried `.trim()` within the PS code now and that also produces the unwanted 15 extra blank lines (in both Ubuntu and CentOS WSL variants). `powershell.exe /c "(get-clipboard -raw).trim()"`

Comment: I just tried your commands and I don't have this problem at all.  I am using WSL1 and tried both Debian and Ubuntu.  There is hope.  It is probably something on your end.  Have you tried cmd.exe and running the same commands?  Have you tried DIRECTLY from powershell itself?

Comment: From PowerShell it is fine, no issues, but you are right, it could be something in my setup (though it's been fairly consistent), I will create a vanilla WSL instance and re-check this.

Comment: @YorSubs PowerShell has a tendency to add unwanted lines when piping to non-PowerShell commands, but 15 extra blank lines would be a bit extreme ;-).  I'm actually suspecting something in your PowerShell profile (assuming you have one?).  Try it with `powershell.exe -NoProfile /c "get-clipboard"`

Comment: This works, thanks, but, it's something about how the PS profile is interacting with WSL specifically, because if I do this in a CMD window, no lines are spawned. I think I see the part of my profile that is to blame, though it's unclear to me why CMD is not affected.

Comment: @YorSubs Glad that helped.  Missed your reply since I wasn't tagged, though.  Would you be able to trim your profile down to just the section that is causing problems and add it to the question?  We can probably figure out the "why" behind it then.